# Cassandra - Set write timeout with Java API

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

I am trying to set the write timeout in Cassandra with the Java drive. SocketOptions allows me to set a read and connect timeout but not a write timeout.
Does anyone knows the way to do this without changing the cassandra.yaml?

thanks

Altober

Answer (score 2):

The name is misleading, but [SocketOptions.getReadTimeoutMillis()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/SocketOptions.html#getReadTimeoutMillis()) applies to all requests from the driver to cassandra.  You can think of it as a client-level timeout.   If a response hasn't been returned by a cassandra node in that period of time an `OperationTimeoutException` will be raised and another node will be tried.   Refer to the javadoc link above for more nuanced information about when the exception is raised to the client.   Generally, you will want this timeout to be greater than your timeouts in cassandra.yaml, which is why 12 seconds is the default.

If you want to effectively manage timeouts at the client level, you can control this on a per query basis by using `executeAsync` along with a timed `get` on the `ResultSetFuture` to give up on the request after a period of time, i.e.:

```
ResultSet result = session.executeAsync("your query").get(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will throw a `TimeoutException` if the request hasn't been completed in 300 ms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But why then in the Cassandra yaml you can set connect, read and write timeouts, how does this reflect in the Java API? In SocketOptions you have only two variables conserning timeouts (connect and read), so where does the default write timeout from the cassandra.yaml ends up? I mean there are three different values in the yaml and only two in the SocketOptions.